# How to read this file on Python 3.4.4?

Tags: python

```
readme = open (r'c:\users\user\desktop\br.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8')

print (readme.read)
```

I have been trying to open a file, but this script isn't working, it says

> built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x00000000036A83A8

Comment: You need to actually *call* the read method. Change `readme.read` to `readme.read()`. Note the parentheses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line into a list with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

you want to call `readme.read()` method to read file.

```
readme = open (r'c:\users\user\desktop\br.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8')
readme.read()
```

if you want to read file line by line you can use.

```
readme.readlines()
```

Comment: Thank you very  much ! i have another question to ask you ,but the site says that i need to wait 3 days , can you help me?